# why does not my opengl program work?

Tags: opengl

I was writing a program to draw a square in my XY plane and make it rotate 360 degree, but it is not working.

```
void setupRC()  
{  
    glClearColor(0,0,1,1);  
    glColor3f(1,0,0);  
}  
void timerfunc(int value)  
{  
    glutPostRedisplay();  
    glutTimerFunc(33, timerfunc ,1);  
}    
void RenderScene()   
{  
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);  
    glLoadIdentity();  
    static GLfloat rot = 0.0f,x =0.0f , y=10.0f , z=0.0f;  
    rot++;  
    x = 10 * cos(rot);  
    y = 10 * sin(rot);  
    glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(rot,0.0,1.0,0.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3i(10,-10,0);
    glVertex3i(10,10,0);
    glVertex3i(-10,10,0);
    glVertex3i(-10,-10,0);
    glVertex3i(10,-10,0);
    glEnd();  
    glPopMatrix();  
    glutSwapBuffers();  
}  
void ChangeSize(GLint w, GLint h)  
{  
    if(h==0)  
        h = 1;  
    GLfloat aspectratio = (GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h;  

    glViewport(0,0,w,h);  
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  
    glLoadIdentity();  
    gluPerspective(60.0f, aspectratio, -1.0, 400.0);  
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);  
    glLoadIdentity();  

}  

int main(int argc , char **argv)  
{  
    glutInit(&argc, argv);  
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);  
    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);  
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);  
    glutCreateWindow("chelsea");  
    glutTimerFunc(33, timerfunc , 1);  
    setupRC();  
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);  
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);  
    glutMainLoop();  

    return 0;  
}
```

I get no output, just a blank screen.

Comment: well, i have listed my main as well sir,
it creates a window, calls the reshape function, display functio and a setup function

Answer (score 2):

gluPerspective(60.0f, aspectratio, -1.0, 400.0);

Looks wrong, the near clipping plane needs to be a positive number

Comment: how can we find what the near and far are?

Comment: Set near to something very small like 0.1 - everything with a Z value smaller than this won't show. Same for the far parameter, everything greater than this will disappear.

Comment: so sir where does this z value start?
i mean if z = 0 means what and the one i have written there is what i took from superbible. they have used a -ve value.
and also i have edited my program.
just have a look again. i didnt do much with the gluperspective part. check the glRotatef that i have included.thank you

Comment: You have to work it out for your application. Basically what is the smallest distance from the camera you want to see things and the greatest. It can't be 0. So 0.1 and 20.0 would be reasonable for your program if I'm understanding it correctly.

z = 0 starts zero distance away from the "camera" position but you can't use that as the math doesn't work out if you do Less than zero makes no sense as you can't see things behing the camera position.

You want to keep them as close to what you need as possible as the bigger they are the worse the precision in your z buffer will be.

Comment: i am still in the shade,
let me put it wat i understud
is it that
the near value is the distance between the camera and the origin ie z=0 and far value is the distance detween the camera and the far as i want the camera to see?

Answer (score 1):

You should really use `glRotatef` for rotating, because your code is wrong if you want a plane rotating around XY (`x` and `y` will be 0 for some values of `rot` and you'll get to see nothing at all).

<strike>And you should perhaps give your polygons a color using the `glColor` commands.</strike>

As JB said, your `gluPerspective` call seems wrong, too. See [this link](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) for a reference.

Comment: OK,sir let me try it. thank you and i have given the color in the setupRC()
glColor3f

Comment: Ah, didn't recognize that, OK.